# Vertical position of cable railing tightening anchors for stairs

Tags: stairs, cables, railing

I am installing cable railing parallel and below my stair banister. They will be anchored in the newel posts. I am using a simple anchor (picture right) on one side and a tightening one (picture left) on the other.

[image]

Does it matter which of the two takes which vertical position? E.g. is it important that the tightening anchor be on top or on the bottom of the stairs or does it matter?

Comment: I would recommend all the simple ones at one end and the adjustable ones at the other end, which ever way you go, just so they look consistent.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter. I'd put the larger one where it's less conspicuous.

Answer (score 2):

I would want the adjustable one where you can work on it at ground level not or having to stand on the stairs to make adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Since it has moving parts I would place it up top, where it will be (slightly) more protected from the elements and grime, presumably in the shadow of the bannister/rail. That's not a huge reason, but it is a reason. If it looked like a robot factory in an otherwise pretty spot, that would probably rule out that placement for me.